# How to get month from To_CHAR in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using To_Char to convert a date to a string in the following format :

```
To_char(Date,'DD Month YYYY HH24:MI')
```

This works great however it returns the month with some spaces. I guess it's desgined such that all the month strings have the same lenght:

## Current result

```
01 January  2020 13:15
01 February 2020 13:15
01 March    2020 13:15       << Spaces after the month string
01 April    2020 13:15       << Spaces after the month string
01 May      2020 13:15       << Spaces after the month string
01 June     2020 13:15       << Spaces after the month string
```

## Desired result

```
01 January 2020 13:15
01 February 2020 13:15
01 March 2020 13:15       << No spaces after the month string
01 April 2020 13:15       << No spaces after the month string
01 May 2020 13:15         << No spaces after the month string
01 June 2020 13:15        << No spaces after the month string
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that please directly from To_char function ? (without doing some specific string replacements like **replace(To_char(Date,'DD Month YYYY HH24:MI'),' double spaces ',' single space ');**

Thanks
Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fm` modifier on `month`:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'DD FMMonth YYYY HH24:MI')
from dual
```